# pig hadoop needed for I want to do?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, required

I have a question for you, well a clarification...

I developed a program that uses hadoop map reduce wich gets just a column from a dataset (csv file) and process this data with some functions, so this program is finished, but the real question is
Is a good idea to develop this program in Pig? note that in the process of the file I dont use FILTERS COUNTS or any built in function of Pig...

Am I right if I say that passing this hadoop map reduce program to Pig has no sense? because all my functions will need to be rewrited as a Pig User Defined Function UDF...

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion there is actually not really a need to write your very small script in PigLatin. It'll be more interesting when its getting bigger, because PigLatin requires less lines of code than java, and its more readable, especially to non-java-developer :)